# Spark RDD map and mapPartitions, is order of rows generated the same?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Something on the lines of :
rdd.map(x=> x*x)
versus
rdd.mapPartitions( x=> x.map(c=> c*c))

Will the transformed RDD generated in both cases be of the same order?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order (assuming it is deterministic and there are no wide transformations upstream) will be the same. `map(f)` is just a shortcut for  dd.mapPartions(_.map(f))`.

However in general case you should never depend on the order of values in `RDD`, unless this explicitly defined using unambiguous (like sort over unique values) or job consist of only narrow transformations with source being a deterministic input format (like one used with `textFile`).